# Adding more claims to Windows Azure AD

Tags: azure, wif, azure-active-directory

I have been struggling to understand how AD works in Azure.
I have an web application and I would like to use WAAD to provide claims to the app. From what I saw until now the only claim provide is the username.
Is there a way to add external claims to Azure AD?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not at this time.  However, you can use the graph API to retrieve more information about users and other directory objects. You can also use the Graph API to extend the directory schema to store your own attributes that can then be queried through Graph. However, the schema extensions feature is still in preview.  See the following links for more information:

Graph API overview:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh974476.aspx

Using the Graph API:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn151791.aspx

Detailed walk through of using WIF to access the graph API:
http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/01/22/group-amp-role-claims-use-the-graph-api-to-get-back-isinrole-and-authorize-in-windows-azure-ad-apps/

Schema extensions walk through:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aadgraphteam/archive/2014/03/06/extend-azure-active-directory-schema-using-graph-api-preview.aspx